# Is there a one-macro way to prefix and quote C macro argument

Tags: c, macros

So when looking into getting my define macro to work, I found the `#` and `##` macro helpers, and used them to simplify my macro. The key part of the macro sets a variable to a string containing the name of the variable (but not the variable name alone). As a simplified example, let's take a macro called `SET(X)` that should expand `SET(something)` into `something = "pre_something"`.

The only way I've found to do it so far is with two macros like `#define QUOTE(X) #X` and `#define SET(X) X = QUOTE(pre_##X)`. However, using multiple macros seems excessive, and may cause problems with further macro expansion (I think). Is there a cleaner, one-line way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#define SET(x) x = "pre_"#x`

C does string concatenation at compile time, so two string literals next to each other are concatenated.

`"hello " "world"` -> `"hello world"`